# Implementing custom Ctrl+a in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, events, keydown, ctrl

How can I implement modified behavior when the user clicks <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (select all).
I tried modifying the `keyDown:` event but it didn't seem to catch the event.

Comment: Do you mean ⌘+A, or would like the ability to use ctrl+A?

Comment: You need to ensure that the view controller is first responder, else it will never see those key down events.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is generally mapped to `selectAll:` on the first responder.  You should be able to simply implement the `selectAll:` method on any responder in the chain and it'll "just work".

Comment: And standard views such as NSTextView will already respond to `selectAll:` and friends, so for text selection, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: `keyDown:` is called and when I log the window's first responder in that, it's the same as this view but `selectAll:` isn't called. Wonder why.

Comment: Got it, that's because I'm not calling `super`'s implementation in `keyDown:`.

Comment: Responded too early. `selectAll:` doesn't get called even when `super`'s implementation of `keyDown:` is called with the same event.

Comment: That was because I had set the table view to not accept selections.